# How to pass a List from the View to the Controller in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have a Product ViewModel where I have a list of objects

```
public List<ValueStream> ListValueStream { get; set; } //ProductViewModel.cs
```

In my View, I decided to use a ListBoxFor in order to select multiples entries.

```
using (var context = new TempoV2.DAL.TempoV2Context())
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.ListValueStream, new SelectList(context.ValueStream.ToList(), "Id", "Name"))
}
```

It displays correctly, however when I select multiple entries, it says that

> The value '4,5,6' is invalid

I look up in the database, and 4, 5 and 6 match the ValueStream that I selected.

If I understand correctly, it does not match the model from the ViewModel.

So how can I manage to pass a List from the view to the controller?

Comment: You cannot bind a list box to a collection of complex objects (its only posts back an array of simple values - the values of the selected options). You need a property to bind to (say) `IEnumerable<int> ListValueStream` assuming the `Id` property of `ValueStream` is `int`

Comment: And since you have a view model, that view model should contain a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (database access code belongs in the controller, not the view)